# Linux's INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST,

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have find a lot of references to `INIT_LIST_HEAD` but I couldn't find anything on `INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST`. what's the differences between the two.

```
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&orig_event->list);
INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST(orig_event->event_list);
INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST(orig_event->rt_hist_list);
```

one pass in the address of thing pointed by a pointer and another pass in just something pointed by a pointer.

```
INIT_HLIST_HEAD(&bat_priv->gw.list);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&bat_priv->tt.changes_list);
```

Also what are differences between `INIT_LIST_HEAD` and `INIT_HLIST_HEAD`?

Comment: Where do you see INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST in the Linux kernel?  I cannot find it in the [lxr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the definitions for each macro,  from `list-batman.h`:

```
00062 #define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
00063        (ptr)->next = (ptr); \
00064 } while (0)
00065 
00066 #define INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST(ptr) \
00067        ptr.next = (struct list_head *)&ptr; ptr.prev = (struct list_head *)&ptr; \
00068
```

(Line 68 is blank, so the continuation from line 67 doesn't do anything.)

So, what does it mean? This question explains the peculiar `do {` . . . `} while (0)` construction:
[Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros)
Thus, `INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr)` is meant to step forward to the next list element.

The `INIT_LIST_HEAD_FIRST(ptr)` sets the next and previous pointers of a `list_head` structure, which is the empty state of a doubly linked list.

I'm puzzled about the *names* of the macros, because both sound like initializations, but that's a question for the developers who wrote the code.

More:

I initially overlooked the question about `INIT_HLIST_HEAD`. I looked it up, and `linux/list.h` defines it as this:

```
 #define INIT_HLIST_HEAD(ptr) ((ptr)->first = NULL)
```

It deals with the `hlist_node` structure, which contains a `next` pointer and a `pprev` pointer to pointer. The macro initializes the list.